# Keras MLP extracting predictions from each cross validation

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

I have built a sequential Keras MLP and would like to extract the predicted labels (Not Accuracy) at each cross validation (CV=5). I also need to extract the cross validation `X_test` data that it tests on at each iteration.

Is this possible?

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(units = 56, input_dim = 11, activation = "relu", 
kernel_initializer= initializer))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(units = 28, activation = "relu"))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(units = 1, activation = "sigmoid"))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=GradDesc12, 
metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(X_train,y_train, epochs= 20, batch_size = 
128,verbose=0)

kFold = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=5)
for train, test in kFold.split(X_data, Y_labels):
```

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to SO. How did you run the cross-validation? Is this in a for loop or something else? Please share your code with details. Thank you.

Comment: @Kaveh Im unsure how to perform it properly. I have edited the post to show my first steps, I have found KFold to be useable in Keras however I am still unsure if this is the correct method .

Comment: `KFold`, helps you split your dataset into `n` folds. In your for loop (last line) you need to get the splitted data and run `model.fit` on them. Now you have not only each split of data, but also can predict after each iteration at the end of for loop with `model.predict`.

Comment: @Kaveh, giving me an error with the `model.fit(train)`

Comment: `  ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer "sequential_5" (type Sequential).
    
    Input 0 of layer "dense_15" is incompatible with the layer: expected min_ndim=2, found ndim=1. Full shape received: (None,)
    
    Call arguments received:
      • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(None,), dtype=int64)
      • training=True
      • mask=None`